# How to combine Git hook with Sonar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, sonarqube

I need a help in the followings.

1. How to add pre-hook stuff in git?
2. How to i make git to run the sonar test before the code commit in vs code?
3. How can i only do with current commit ( not already pushed code )

I keep searching a solution across the web. but getting no valid and detailed demo, tutorials. please any one help me to understand all above?

Thanks in advance.